# Numbers bigger than 20 digits

Tags: c++

I did a basic program for counting how many even numbers are in the input. For numbers smaller than 20 it works.But when I type a value bigger than 20 digits for n, it displays number 9. I understand that 20 digits is bigger than long long, but why doesn't it display the result for the first 20 characters? Is there any way I could make it work for numbers bigger than 20 digits?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n, p=0;
cout<<"n=";
cin>>n;

for( int i=1; i<n; n=(n/10))
    if ((n%10)%2==0)
        p=(p+1);

cout<<p ;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Save it in a `std::string` and loop through every character or use a `BigInteger` library.

Comment: Handle stuff as strings and not integers?

Comment: Thanks.  I did not think about using strings

Comment: "why doesn't it display the result for the first 20 characters?" Because that's not how `>>` works. If the number is too big, then `>>` fails, but you never checked for failure.